# Yocto how to add a gstreamer plugin?

Tags: opencv, gstreamer, yocto, bitbake

I'm trying to build a custom image for an i.MX6 board by using Yocto.
I want to add the plugin 'gstmotioncells' from Gstreamer OpenCV Plugins  ( https://github.com/GStreamer/gst-plugins-bad/tree/master/ext/opencv )
to my build.

But I can't figure out how to add this plugin to my yocto build.
I tried some things but these have not worked.
Do I need to add something to my local.conf file or do I need to modify a .bb file?

After following the instructions of jku, I still got an error.

```
ERROR: esomimx6-sta-image-1.0-r0 do_rootfs: Unable to install packages. Command '/home/toon/yocto/sta/esomimx6/build_esom/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-linux/usr/bin/opkg --volatile-cache -f /home/toon/yocto/sta/esomimx6/build_esom/tmp/work/esomimx6micro-poky-linux-gnueabi/esomimx6-sta-image/1.0-r0/opkg.conf -o /home/toon/yocto/sta/esomimx6/build_esom/tmp/work/esomimx6micro-poky-linux-gnueabi/esomimx6-sta-image/1.0-r0/rootfs  --force_postinstall --prefer-arch-to-version   install fsl-alsa-plugins packagegroup-core-ssh-openssh libfreetype6 packagegroup-esom-qt5 cpufrequtils glib-networking libcairo2 openssh-sftp-server packagegroup-core-boot packagegroup-core-x11-base glibmm packagegroup-fsl-gstreamer1.0-full packagegroup-esom-tools-testapps alsa-state ruby packagegroup-fsl-gstreamer1.0 packagegroup-fsl-tools-gpu gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad-opencv packagegroup-fsl-tools-testapps packagegroup-core-tools-debug opkg packagegroup-base-extended libfontconfig1' returned 255:
Collected errors:
 * opkg_prepare_url_for_install: Couldn't find anything to satisfy 'gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad-opencv'.
```

Do you know what is going wrong?

Answer (score 3):

As a first step, you need to enable the opencv plugin in the gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad recipe. There's a packageconfig for that already so this should work in local.conf or your distro configuration:

```
PACKAGECONFIG_append_pn-gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad = " opencv"
```

(The space in front of the string is required)

This will make the recipe depend on opencv which is not in the oe-core layer. You will have to add meta-oe to your layers if it's not there already.

You'll also want to add the relevant packages to your image: Probably  at least `gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad-opencv`. In production this would probably happen so that an application recipe that requires the opencv plugin would DEPEND on it. For testing you can just add

```
 IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad-opencv"
```

into your local.conf.

Comment: Can you describe how I should do the last step? How I add packages to my image?

Comment: I had a minute so tried this. $WORKDIR/temp/log.do_configure shows gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad still silently disabled opencv plugin. configure.ac explains why https://github.com/GStreamer/gst-plugins-bad/blob/1.10/configure.ac#L2737-L2743 . The opencv version in meta-oe is 3.2 so does not match what this version of gstreamer expects. Two options: 1) Try patching the configure.ac to accept 3.2.0 -- _maybe_ it's compatible. 2) Try with an older opencv: there's 2.4 in meta-oe: `PREFERRED_VERSION_opencv = "2.4"` should do it in local.conf -- I have no idea if this older recipe is being tested though

Comment: Never mind the 2.4 suggestion: the recipe is blacklisted so definitely is not being tested.

Comment: Since gstreamer 1.6 is only supporting opencv  2.4, I had to backport opencv to my build. And I didn't need the 'IMAGE_INSTALL_append'